# ASP.NET Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point where garbage collection is impossible

Tags: asp.net

I have a weird problem, I get an object from my DB, like this:

```
var user = BLL.Managers.Users.UserTmpManager.GetUser((int)customerID);
```

when I debug that code, and expand the user object, for each property I see the error as I mentioned at this topic's title. What causes it ?

unfortunately, it is still not being resolved, as I thought at the beginning..

Comment: Have you actually stepped into "GetUser" at the point you are seeing the above error?  Or are you just stopped at this line by a break point/stepping through code?

Comment: I stopped into that method and I saw that everything is OK, but when I step out of that methiod, the error appears

Comment: So that error appears when you are executing and the cursor is at the next line of code?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to rebuild the whole project again, without success

Comment: That metod works fine everywhere else, but where it's really needed - just fails

Answer (score 0):

I got this too, when I hit a NullReferenceException from a 3rd party control.

In this one case, I found that if I set a breakpoint **before** I hit the exception, I could then single step through the rest of the code without seeing the problem.

No idea why, but this worked for me - in this case at least.