# getting setting from web.config in sitecore

Tags: web-config, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

i want to get global setting from web.config file in sitecore solution,
 i write setting in config file and able to see it's entry in showconfig. when i try to get it's value, it is not giving appropriate value. my code is like this:

```
 var newsBodyTemplateID = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("NewsBody");
```

when i evaluate this, it giving this message:
[image]

what i'm missing here can some figure out it.

Comment: Could it be that you don't have Sitecore context when you are trying to read the setting

Comment: yes there i'm not able to read sitecore context

Comment: so what should i do for read this,

Comment: We'll need more info around where you are making this call. Is it in a web service?

Comment: no, it is a class library project, where i defined all models

Comment: Have a look at this answer to a related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348263/202. What do you actually get when you just runt the application? Exception? Empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method will return settings from the `Sitecore\Settings` node. there is another method to get `AppSettings`.

```csharp
Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetAppSetting()
```

Comment: can you add the exact path of you setting node (i.e. configuration\appsettings\...`) to your question

Comment: i'm working in siteoore with MVC, in case of view it's working but when i try to get in different library project it's giving above defined message.

Comment: i put it in app_config/include/myconfig.config

Comment: I meant the location within the config not the file path. Try going to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`  to make sure the setting is where it's supposed to be

Comment: it's at the right place, under <Settings>, and one more thing when i get it on my view it's working.

Comment: OP said he is using a Sitecore setting not an AppSetting. This does not answer the question. If it was an AppSetting he wouldn't be seeing it on the ShowConfig page

Comment: When I answered, all OP had said was "get global setting from web.config file in sitecore solution". The other info came much later

Answer (score 8):

First of all I don't recomment to add in web.config your settings. If you want to upgrade your Sitecore than you have to merge manually your web.config.

If you still want to add setttings in web.config you need to have something like :

```xml
 <configuration>

     .....
      <appSettings>
        <add key="YourSeetings" value="your value" />
         ...
        </appSettings>

     .....
      </configuration>
```

From C# code you need to  use

```cs
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourSeetings"]
```

If you have your settings   on section /configuration/sitecore/settings
you need to use from C# code :

```cs
Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("yoursettingsname");
```

Your config file will looks like :

```xml
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>

    <!-- General settings -->
    <settings>
        <setting name="YourSettingsFieldName" value="{1EPR25B2-98C6-45BF-B9E4-824ECAAEF499}" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: it's sitecore configuration, i'm not writing appSetting for the application

Comment: i'm doing same thing, but couldn't able to get settings

Comment: OP said he is using a Sitecore setting not an AppSetting. This does not answer the question. If it was an AppSetting he wouldn't be seeing it on the ShowConfig page

Comment: This is the correct answer... if by any chance your code is not picking up the config setting make sure that when you publish to your sitecore the actual .config is being publish... click the .config file and check the properties "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Copy Always" but always take caution when doing this.